# How to generate automatically click events in VS 2012 in web project?

Tags: events, visual-studio-2012, handler

I was looking for so long how to generate automatically event handlers for example for a button in a WEB PROJECT. In properties window there is no icon for adding event handlers. If somebody knows how to add it to one of the navigation windows I will be glad to see the answer.

The screen how it looks in my Visual Studio 2012:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/fh6.png/

When I am in a C# Forms projects I can see this event handler icon in a properties window.